# Command-H producing fatal error in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have an osx App with two NSOutlineViews in it. When I press a button, an object is added to each NSOutlineView. While debugging my program, I found a strange error. When I press Command - h (the hide application command), click the app icon (to unhide the app), and then press the button to add the object to both NSOutlineViews, I get an error:

> <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

This appears to only happen if i hide the window and then press the button. Furthermore, the error actually mentioned my internet connection. I have since blocked command - h, but I am concerned about releasing this App when I do not know why this happened. Why might hiding the window have caused this error?

Comment: If the application is hidden, how can you be pressing the button? It's hidden.

Comment: @matt whoops. I meant when I click the app icon again. I edited the question, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Does the app actually crash? When developing for iOS this error comes up quite often in the simulator and it's an acknowledged framework bug. If you're not doing any core graphics drawing yourself, it could be the same case.

Comment: @jrturton So are you saying I should just ignore this error?

Comment: I'm saying that, if you're not doing any drawing, it's probably not your bug. What did you mean about it mentioning your internet connection?

Comment: @jrturton I am on a university internet wifi and it mentioned "myUniversityName.private" at the beginning of the error message